# Is there way to make the apexchart tooltip a clickable vuejs javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bar-chart, apexcharts

I am trying to visualize the data with using Apexcharts bar chart. In there, the tooltip works fine, but need to add link to the tooltip so I can click these and go to that website. So is there any way to do it. This is the code snippet I am using right now.

```
let chartDomainData = [];

function getDomainDataFromIndex(index) {
     return chartDomainData[index];
}



      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        custom: function ({dataPointIndex}) {
          return `<div class="arrow-box
            ${
              getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).label === "low"
                  ? "bg-yellow"
                  : "bg-blue"
          }
                ">
                <p> Label=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).label} credibility
                </p>
                <p> No of tweets=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).y}
                </p>
                <p> Website=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).x}
                </p>
                <p> Source=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).platform}
                </p>
                </div>`;
        },
      },
```

Is there anyone who can help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

If your tooltip content is displaying your html correctly, you should be able to simply add a `<a>` link to it.

I don't know how you want it to work, if for example you want to display a link in the end of your tooltip you can add, after `<p> Source= ...</p>`:

`<a :href="yourLink">website</a>`

If you want your whole tooltip to redirect to a website you could try something like:

```
tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        custom: function ({dataPointIndex}) {
          return `<a href="yourLink"><div class="arrow-box
            ${
              getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).label === "low"
                  ? "bg-yellow"
                  : "bg-blue"
          }
                ">
                <p> Label=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).label} credibility
                </p>
                <p> No of tweets=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).y}
                </p>
                <p> Website=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).x}
                </p>
                <p> Source=
                ${getDomainDataFromIndex(dataPointIndex).platform}
                </p>
                </div></a>`;
        },
      },
```

Comment: The thing in here is it's not clickable. Can add a link inside the tooltip. But can not click it.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't understand your problem, maybe they set a `pointer-events: none` to the tooltip, can you try to add `.apexcharts-tooltip { pointer-events: auto !important; }` ?

Comment: Sorry, where to add the .apexcharts-tooltip { pointer-events: auto !important; }. I didn't get it.

Comment: My idea was to update the `apexcharts-tooltip` class, so you can try to add `.apexcharts-tooltip { pointer-events: auto !important; }` in your <style> so that it overwrites the css of apexcharts

Comment: I tried with `pointer-events: none; ` and `{ pointer-events: auto !important; }`, seems they are being ignored.

Comment: ok sorry so I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this by just manipulating the CSS of the tooltip.

`.apexcharts-tooltip { pointer-events: auto; }`

Hope this helps.